# Google Maps iOS SDK, area custom color

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

im developing a iOS app using Google Map iOS SDK, and i have a question about the "style", like CSS Google Maps options, there is an option using iOS for apply custom style like background color to some area like this example

[Google Map Style](https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/customizing/styling-the-base-map)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The Google SDK for iOS doesn't currently support custom styles.

You might be able to wrap the javascript map styles in a web view.   B